# Model backing applicationdbcontext context has changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

The problem I am having is that someone has added extra columns to the database table directly and now I am getting the error above.  I have tried just changing the model to match the table schema however this yielded no results, I had a swift google around but couldn't really find a post similar to my situation, I probably haven't looked properly.  I also cannot see the entity framework designer to update my model from database。  I don't seem to have any EDMX files also I used the package manager console in order to generate my database and tables by running the commands Add-Migration and Update-Database

Comment: EDMX, database first? Right-click the designer and select "Update Model from Database...".

Comment: @CodeCaster I can't seem to find the designer to be able to do this.  My database is sitting on a remote machine

Comment: You double-click the EDMX file, if you have any. Please [edit] your question to include how you use Entity Framework (EDMX / Code First) and how you generated the initial model or database.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have updated my post I do not have any EDMX files and I have been updating my models through the package manager console by running the commands Add-Migration and Update-Database

Comment: Then you should just be able to fix up the models (as you did) and add a migration like `Add-Migration FixingIssueCausedByDeveloperNotFollowingCodeFirstConvention`, followed by an `Update-Database`.

Comment: So I've tried that but got an error: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'tree' in table 'dbo.dbOID' is specified more than once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956905/ef5-code-first-migrations-column-names-in-each-table-must-be-unique-error-aft