# EntityFramework does not add __MigrationHistory record

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, msdeploy

While publishing [ASP.NET WebApi + EF6 + SlowCheetah + Azure SQL] webapp from VisualStudio 2015, production database schemas are updated without adding new migration record to `__MigrationHistory`.

For this reason, it always failed on EF model binding with error message as below;

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'SomeProperty' in table 'dbo.CommandModels' is specified more than once.

Weired thing is that, `web.config.dev` is applied to development database without any trouble, but `web.config.production` makes such problem. Both config files have same hierarchy except database connectionstring and `Publish` wizard have checked `Update Database` identically.

To fix this, I always run `update-database -f -script`, copy the last line (below quoted script), and execute it in SSMS or VS after publishing. This remedy is given from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957069/361100.

> INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
>   VALUES (N'201610070644166_AddAppId', N'Recognition.WebApi.Migrations.Configuration',  0x1F8B0800000000000400ED5CDD6C00E3377481D67897B9418EFA035E217753DC80C62C8C4C0000 , N'6.1.3-40302')

Why is this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad.

I checked at `LogConnectionString` for `[v] update database`, not `DefaultConnection` in the `Publish > Settings` dialog. It was invisible by scroll range.

If someone has same issue, double-check that you ticked to right connectionstring.